# UIAlertView and UIWebView don't work after migration to Xcode 7

Tags: uiwebview, uialertview, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I wrote the below swift code in Xcode 7, but 'UIAlertView' was deprecated in iOS 9.0. Moreover, the webview display nothing. It was working well in Xcode 6.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "This App needs internet connection",

        message: "If not connected now, please make sure your device connect to internet and restart it.",

        delegate: nil,

        cancelButtonTitle: "OK")



    alert.show()


    let URL = NSURL(string: "http://saloonjob.com/catering")

    WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)UIAlertView**

Starting from iOS8, **UIActionSheet and UIAlertView are being replaced by the new UIAlertController.**

An instance of the UIAlertController can be presented modally on screen just as any other UIViewController using the presentViewController:animated:completion: method. What makes the UIAlertController instance differentiate between working as an ActionSheet or as an AlertView is the style parameter you pass when creating it.

**2)WebView**

“If you’re developing a new app, you should use HTTPS exclusively. If you have an existing app, you should use HTTPS as much as you can right now, and create a plan for migrating the rest of your app as soon as possible,” Apple explains in its pre-release documentation for iOS 9.
check with HTTPS url ,webview will load..

Comment: let URL = NSURL(string: "https://www.ssls.com")
        
        WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))

Comment: but i still got output statment "2015-10-05 18:03:51.204 HKCateringApp[1326:45336] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)"

Comment: I don't understand what it means, i am using https.

Answer (score 0):

**2) WebView:**
It is not enough to use HTTPS.
In addition, the server should support the latest SSL technology.

Please read this article:
http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

If you don't have control on the server side then you can add this flag to the info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Pay attention to the DANGER note, you should avoid this solution.